# UIImageView "bounce in" animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on figuring out how to animate a UIImageView like so:

On the initial load of the app, a UIImageView will come in from the top of the screen and then bounce (up and down) into the bottom a couple times before settling at the bottom.

I know how to animate it where it just moves along the Y axis, but how to do the slight bounce effect at the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this (I've used this method with great success) is to use nested animations.  You could take advantage of the [UIView + (void)animateWithDuration:animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) method.

Here's the ***pseudo*** for it:

```
Animation{
    //Fall to the bottom along the y axis
    [self doFallToBottom];
    onCompletion:
    {
          Animation{
             //Hits the bottom.  Bounce up a bit along the y axis (maybe 100 pixels or so)
             [self bounceUp:100];
             onCompletion:
             {
                //Fall back down to the bottom along the y axis
                [self doFallToBottom];
             }
          }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this will work, I will prefer to create one single CAKeyframeAnimation and add a path to it. Adding a single path looks easier to me than to keep track of sequential animations via animation end delegate method.

Comment: Your idea sounds great.  My original concern with that is the inability to manage the durations for each frame, but it looks like CAKeyframeAnimation gives you that ability.  Good idea!

Comment: If we want different up and down speed then I guess your method will be better. Not sure whether it is possible to set different time for different path components. However, if we want a overall slowdown then kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut can be used as timing function.

Answer (score 1):

[MoveMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/moveme/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple demonstrate a bouncing animation. Check the method `- (void)animatePlacardViewToCenter` in `MoveMeView` class. It creates a `bounceAnimation`. As you need bouncing only in y axis, it will be easier to implement than the sample.